# Dynamically Insert Content After Mutation Observed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I have a dynamic product list.  On page load, the list of products and data are populated by an API.  When someone sorts or filters the products, the data is refreshed and repainted to the page.  Some product containers may have updated data, while others do not (depending on how the user sorted)

I need to dynamically calculate the discount (money saved) whenever the filter/sort is applied.

I'm trying to do this via a mutationObserver, which observes any changes to the price of a product.

My observer works just fine, I am just struggling on how to insert the discount into the DOM tree when the observer detects a change.  Again, some of the products will have updated data, while others don't.

My biggest struggle is ***how do I connect the mutation record to the DOM element*** so that I can make changes?  For example, if products one and four data changed, how do I target only those DOM elements to insert/change my content?

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="product one">
        <div class="prodImg"></div>
        <div class="prodDesc"></div>
        <div class="origPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodAddtoCart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product two">
        <div class="prodImg"></div>
        <div class="prodDesc"></div>
        <div class="origPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodAddtoCart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product three">
        <div class="prodImg"></div>
        <div class="prodDesc"></div>
        <div class="origPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodAddtoCart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product four">
        <div class="prodImg"></div>
        <div class="prodDesc"></div>
        <div class="origPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodPrice"></div>
        <div class="prodAddtoCart"></div>
    </div>
</div>


var targetNode = document.querySelector(".mainContainer");
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData:true };

var callback = (mutationList, observer) => {

for (const mutation of mutationList) {
  if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
    if (mutation.target.parentElement.className === 'prodPrice') {
        //my psuedo code would look something like this
        $(this).closest('.product').find('.prodAddtoCart').after('<div class="discount">$xx.xx</div>')

     }
    }
}

};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Comment: would it not be apparent in `mutationList` that only products 1 and 4 changed?

Comment: Instead of mutation observer, doesn't the API have a callback function that can be called after it updates/sorts the content? That would seem like the better option

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `$(mutation.target.parentElement).closest('.product').find('.prodAddtoCart').after('<div class="discount">$xx.xx</div>')`. Your code doesn't know what `$(this)` means in that context

Comment: @TKoL I am new to mutation observers, but from what I understand, the mutations records returned after based on nodes, so I am not 100% if using a jquery notation would work...do you have any experience with that?

Comment: You use jQuery on the wrong target (`this` is probably undefined or equals to `window`). The comment above suggests a possible solution.

Comment: @TKoL You're solution worked for me.  If you want to create an answer rather than a comment, I can upvote it and mark it as correct.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.product').find('.prodAddtoCart').after('<div class="discount">$xx.xx</div>')
```

The function doesn't know what `this` is at that point, but you already have a reference to the object, `mutation.target.parentElement`:

```
$(mutation.target.parentElement).closest('.product').find('.prodAddtoCart').after('<div class="discount">$xx.xx</div>')
```